# Ошибка чтения из файла в java

Tags: java, файлы, исключения, io

Я написал следующую программу, читающую количетсво компьютеров из текстового фалйа, содержащего просто число

```
import java.io.*;

public class ReadFromFile {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int CountComputers=0;
        try {
        DataInputStream ConfigFile = new DataInputStream( new 
         FileInputStream("D:\\HadoopFolder\\ReadFromFile\\src\\countcomputers.txt"));
        CountComputers=ConfigFile.readInt();
        ConfigFile.close(); 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //CountComputers=ConfigFile.readInt();
        System.out.println("Количество компьютеров равно "+CountComputers);
    }

}
```

Выдает следующую ошибку

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
    at ReadFromFile.main(ReadFromFile.java:16)
```

Также у меня есть вопрос обязательно ли надо чтение из файла заключать в try ... expect(в одном проекте подчеркнуло красным, а в другом тоже на java (он был несколько другого рода) нет). Я новичок в Java, поэтому просьба отнестись с пониманием.

Comment: это не правильная строчка в любом случае.. у тебя там в файле только 1 цифра?
CountComputers=ConfigFile.readInt();

Comment: @Gorets , да в файле D:\\HadoopFolder\\ReadFromFile\\src\\countcomputers.txt записано число 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В "святых" доках написано [сие](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readInt()) :)

```
public int readInt() throws IOException
```

Reads **four input bytes** and returns an int value. Let a be the first byte read, b be the second byte, c be the third byte, and d be the fourth byte. The value returned is:

```
(((a & 0xff) << 24) | ((b & 0xff) << 16) | ((c & 0xff) << 8) | (d & 0xff))
```

А у Вас в файле скорей всего число из 1-2 знаков - поэтому и ругается. Можно переписать вот таким образом:

```
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("file.txt"); // путь к файлу
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String result = br.readLine(); // читаем как строку
CountComputers = Integer.parseInt(result); // переводим строку в число
```

На счет try/catch - почитайте об исключениях, есть два вида - checked и unchecked, checked - нужно брать в try/catch или выбрасывать наверх, unchecked - не обязательно.